# How to count item occurences in BASH array?

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array `${myarr[@]}` with strings. `${myarr[@]}` basically consists of lines and each line constists of words.

```
world hello moon
weather dog tree
hello green plastic
```

I need to count the occurences of `hello` in this array. 
How do I do it?

Comment: If there are multiple "hello"s on 1 line, grep -c will count that as 1  occurrence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
for word in ${myarr[*]}; do
  echo $word
done | grep -c "hello"
```

Answer (score 9):

Alternative (without loop):

```
grep -o hello <<< ${myarr[*]} | wc -l
```

Don't get tempted to change it to `grep -oc hello`. It counts the number of lines that contain `hello`. So, if some line contains more than 1 instances of the word, it will still be counted as 1.

Alternately, this would work too:

```
printf '%s\n' ${myarr[*]} | grep -cFx hello
```

The lack of quotes around `${myarr[*]}` tokenizes it and printf will then print the words on separate lines. Then grep -c will count those.

Note:

The first approach will count a single word hello_some_string_here_hello as 2 instances of hello.
The second approach will count them as zero instances (match whole line with `-x`)

Comment: Thanks, really nice and clean solution

Answer (score 7):

No need for an external program:

```
count=0
for word in ${myarr[*]}; do
    if [[ $word =~ hello ]]; then
        (( count++ ))
    fi
done 

echo $count
```